# Get empty strings from <h:inputText> go through validation

Tags: validation, jsf

Is there a way to make jsf validator handle empty strings? 
I have a custom validator for all inputTexts. 
Instead of having to implement the "required" tag as well I would like to have the customer handler handle the empty strings and determine within the backing bean if that field is mandatory or not.

```
<h:inputText id="SSID_STR" styleClass="propertyInput" value="#{wifiDM.SSIDStr}" validator="#{wifiDM.validate}" >
    <h:message for="SSID_STR" fatalClass="mandatoryFieldMissing" tooltip="true" />
</h:inputText>
```

If I had to add the required tag I would have to do this for every input text in my app:

```
<h:inputText id="SSID_STR" styleClass="propertyInput" value="#{wifiDM.SSIDStr}" validator="#{wifiDM.validate}" required="#{wifiDM.isRequired} requiredMessage="*">
    <h:message for="SSID_STR" fatalClass="mandatoryFieldMissing" tooltip="true" />
    <f:attribute name="InputID" value="SSID_STR">
</h:inputText>
```

which is a mess...

---

**Update (Clarification)**
First of all, using JSF 1.2.
Each field is independent in the sense of being required or not so the issue of component dependency is irrelevant.
My goal was to pass the null value through the validator so I don't have to add both tags to the inputText.

Also, The Validator handler gets 'component' as a parameter, which means I can get its ID and see in **real time** if it is required. (The same component may not always be required).

If I use `required="#{bean.requireCheck}"` (For Example) can I somehow get the component from which it was called?

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html

Comment: Tnx. That actually doesn't have the solution to my problem of validating null string fields. I found a possible solution of implementing my own custom input field. I'm checking it and will update if it works.

Comment: I couldn't understand why it wouldn't work for you /

Comment: The problem i have is that the validation method doesn't get executed for null strings. @BalusC solution doesn't handle that case as well.

Comment: I can't stress this enough, in all of the JSF questions please mention the impl/version used. The absence of a `jsf-2.0` tag is not necessarily enough sign that you're really using JSF 1.x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSF 1.x does by default not fire validators on empty fields. For that the `required` attribute has to be used. If your *concrete* problem is that the second field has to be set `required` whenever the first field is been filled in, then you should just check that so in the `required` attribute.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input1}" binding="#{input1}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input2}" required="#{not empty input1.value}" />
```

If that's not the functional requirement, then you should clarify that more in the question so that a better suited answer can be given.

---

**Update**: So you want to control the requireness from the model on? Add a `Map<String, Boolean>` to the bean as follows:

```
private Map<String, Boolean> required;

public Bean() {
    required = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    required.put("foo", true);
    required.put("bar", false); // false entries are by the way not necessary.
    // ...
}

public Map<String, Boolean> getRequired() {
    return required;
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
<h:inputText id="foo" required="#{bean.required['foo']}" />
<h:inputText id="bar" required="#{bean.required['bar']}" />
```

If you were using JSF 2.0, you could do it as follows

```
<h:inputText id="foo" required="#{bean.required[component.id]}" />
<h:inputText id="bar" required="#{bean.required[component.id]}" />
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, it's illegal to put a `<h:message>` as child of `<h:inputText>`. Put them next to each other.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks. I Added clarification.

Comment: What do you need the component for in `#{bean.requireCheck}`?

Comment: For every component, in any given time, there is a function that returns true of false if the component is required or not. To do that I have to know which component runs the method (Or write a different method for each component, which seems wrong since I have many fields)
Although I might end up doing that since I'm not seeing a solution for my problem other than writing a custom component (which will overwrite the validate() method)

Comment: Yes, but what exactly do you need from the component? What are you doing with `component`? Just `component.getClientId(context)`? Or `component.getId()`? Or whatever.

Comment: `component.getId()` Or `component.getAttributes().get(..)`  will suffice