# JSF: how to replace standard Required Validator

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I have a lot of code with standard required validation.
Something like this

```
<h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="it is required!"/>
```

Now, I need to change behavior of [RequiredValidator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/RequiredValidator.html): put error message to the context, but do not interrupt cycle. May be to do something more.

I tried to add custom validator with the same id, but it did not work.

```
<validator>
    <validator-id>javax.faces.Required</validator-id>
    <validator-class>my.RequiredValidator</validator-class>
</validator>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Empty fields are not committed to validators. I could not find a matching documentation, but I tested the environment and please take a look at [Get empty strings from <h:inputText> go through validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259386/get-empty-strings-from-hinputtext-go-through-validation).

This question also handles an empty string input and BalusC says:

> JSF 1.x does by default not fire validators on empty fields.

OK, it's about JSF 1.X, but it seems it didn't change.

Validators are to interrupt the request, but that's not what you want. So could it be a workaround to use the setter method for your needs?

Ommit the `required` attribute from your `inputText` and add a `FacesMessage` in the setter for your textInput. Assumed the assingned value is `#{myBean.description}`, the setter may look like this:

```
public void setDescription(String value) {
    String _tmp = value.trim();
    if (_tmp.equals("")) {
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR
            , "Error:", "Input must not be empty"));
        this.description = null;
        return;
    }
    this.description = _tmp;
}
```